# Delete user input if higher than assigned variable javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I'm a new programmer learning HTML/CSS/Javascript, and was fiddling around with it until I came across a bug. I was making the computer guess my number (0-5), but then realized if I put in a number higher than 5, the website just crashes. Is there any way I can make it so that if the user puts in a number higher than 5 it will just delete it automatically? Or is that not Javascript. Thanks in advance :)

```
document.getElementById("guess").onclick=function() {

    var gotit=false;
    var guesses=1;
    var x;

    while(gotit==false) {

        x=Math.random();
        x=6*x;
        x=Math.floor(x);

        if(document.getElementById("myNumber").value==x) {
            gotit=true;
        } else {
            guesses++;
        }
    }

    alert("Got it! It was a " + x + ". It only took me " + guesses + " guesses!");

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code that you've implemented so far?

Comment: First, where is `target` defined ? Are you trying to use `event.target` ? Second,, after resetting the value to empty, why are you performing looping ? It will be an infinite loop (assuming `target` is `myNumber` field)

Comment: Was just messing around trying to fix it myself. Edited the code. I'm bad at this >_>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
 document.getElementById("guess").onclick=function() {      
        if(document.getElementById("myNumber").value > 5) {
            document.getElementById("myNumber").value = "";
            alert("Please provide a number that is with in 0 to 5");
        } else {
            var gotit=false;
            var guesses=1;
            var x;

            while(gotit==false) {

                x=Math.random();
                x=6*x;
                x=Math.floor(x);

                if(document.getElementById("myNumber").value==x) {
                    gotit=true;
                } else {
                    guesses++;
                }
            }

            alert("Got it! It was a " + x + ". It only took me " + guesses + " guesses!");
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Simple and quick to understand. Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 1):

Than define a [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) function to check length:

```
document.getElementById("myNumber").onchange  = function (ev){
  try{ 
        var target = document.getElementById("myNumber");
        if(parseInt(target.value) > x) { // can throw exception, when given a non number
          target.value="";
        }
    } catch(ex) {
      alert('Not a number');
    }
};
```

**IMPORTANT**:

You have a greater problem here: You are generating a random number, and then comparing it to input( that does not change). This is an **infinite loop**. Because this is a random operation, and you can hit same number more than once.

You need to generate your number first (before click event on 'guess' button), before clicking on quess button. Like so:

```
var luckyNumber = x;
var guesses=1;

document.getElementById("start").onclick=function(){ //init counters once
    guesses=0;
    x=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    gotit = false;
 }


document.getElementById("guess").onclick=function() { // guess as many times as you want
    if(document.getElementById("myNumber").value==x) {
      gotit=true;
    } 
    guesses++;
    if(gotit){
     alert("Got it! It was a " + x + ". It only took me " + guesses + " guesses!");
    }
}
```

But if you want to computer to quess your number, than you need to limit number of guesses (add a counter), or it will hang eventualy.

Comment: You should have checked for an onchange event handling in javascript, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I took this as a little challenge and just went ahead and re-did your little game. Hope this helps.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/qdbr7nk3/2/)

```
(function (guess, tryy, message) {
    var comp = function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
    };
    var number = comp();
    var count = 0;
    var test = function () {
        var val = guess.value;
        if (!Number.isNaN(val) && val >= 0 && val <= 5) {
            switch (true) {
                case val > number:
                    message.innerHTML = 'Your guess was too high!';
                    count++;
                    break;
                case val < number:
                    message.innerHTML = 'Your guess was too low!';
                    count++;
                    break;
                case val == number:
                    count++;
                    message.innerHTML = 'Congratulations you found the number! It took you ' + count + ' guesses';
                    //Reseting game here
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        count = 0;
                        number = comp();
                        guess.value = '';
                        message.innerHTML = 'Your game has been reset';
                    }, 2000);
                    break;
            };
        }

    };
    tryy.onclick = test;
    guess.onkeyup = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            test();
        }
    }
})(document.getElementById('guess'), document.getElementById('tryy'), document.getElementById('message'));
```

Comment: Wow! That's really neat! Hopefully I can get that good some day :P